# How do I print a local variable if the program is not running in gdb?

Tags: gdb

I have this value, that I know equals something else, but it is giving me a very large value in hex when I try and print it in gdb: -0xc(%ebp)

How do I examine this in gdp to find the int at that location?

EDIT: More information - here are the lines in question:

```
0x08049961 <+88>:   cmpl   $0x3,-0xc(%ebp)
0x08049965 <+92>:   je     0x804996c <level_3+99>
```

I am basically trying to access the value in -0xc(%ebp) to see if the comparison against three is valid. How do I do this? It's spitting out a very large int value in the millions and I know for a fact that cannot be possible.

Comment: `(gdb) x  -0xc+$ebp`? -0xc(%ebp) is the addition of -12 (bytes) to the value of the base pointer, giving a new pointer. You need to dereference it. Also you must have a running program in order for an instance of that variable to exist....

Comment: `(gdb) help x` will show you the different print formats. `x` can _eXamine a memory address_ in multiple formats, including `x/wd` for viewing the pointed-to memory as signed decimal and `x/wx` for hex. `w` here means word-size (4 bytes), `h` means halfword (2 bytes), `b` would mean byte, and `g` means giant (8 bytes).